# Knife tool is not working

Tags: knife-tool

Knife tool isn't working.It doesn't show any selection when i hover over a vertice to start the cut. Anyone knows how to fix it.[image]

Comment: yes I may miss something but it looks like it doesn't work as in 2.7 where you could "snap" the knife to the vertices, maybe it is a question to ask to Blender developers?

Comment: Is it possible that i altered some settings by mistake which i now preventing knife tool from working.I toggled through a couple on-screen settings to check maybe i have accidentally altered some setting but i couldn't find any

Comment: #moonboots if you could provide me with your email id maybe,then i ll forward you my blend file for you to look into.I tried uploading it here but it is giving some error.